# PostScript files do not display in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, postscript

I can't see PostScript files with Safari. The files are loaded into the browser but the window remains gray. It looks like it opens the builtin PDF preview window but nothing happens. Right-click gives a familiar menu but clicking on Open in Preview does nothing. The controls that usually appear when I move the pointer to the bottom center of the window do not appear.

If I download the PostScript file, then it opens fine in Preview.

For sample PostScript files, see [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/ps/ps.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/ps/ps.html), but it happens with all other files I've tried.

Is there a setting I'm missing? Or a fix?

I'm running Safari 15.3 (15612.4.9.1.8, 15612) in macOS 10.15.7 (19H1323). It works fine in Safari 14.1.2 in macOS 10.15.7 and
in Safari 13.1.2 in macOS 10.13.6.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has removed support for PostScript files in the WebKit version that comes with Monterey 12.3.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes

"Support for inline viewing of PostScript files is no longer available."

---

*If PostScript isn't already deprecated, it certainly will be soon, and then entirely unsupported.

"R.I.P." doesn't just stand for Raster Image Processor. :sadface:*

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Thanks for the reference. Then, Safari should download the file, instead of trying and failing to display it. It seems a bug to me.

Comment: @lhf Yes. You can always right-click on the link and select Download there.

Comment: Safari 15.4 downloads PostScript files and opens them in Preview.